# How can I concatenate a string with each element of a vector within a row of a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, concatenation

Forgive my formatting; this is my first question.
I have a dataframe where one of the variables is a string and another of the variables is a vector.
What I would like to do is concatenate the string to each element of the vector within each row of the data frame. The strings are not necessarily all the same lengths. The vectors are not necessarily all the same length.
Basically, I'm trying to get from here:

Dataframe: assignments

| user | task |
| --- | --- |
| `'Bill'` | `c(1, 2, 3)` |
| `'Jae'` | `c(2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)` |
| `'Marsha'` | `c(1, 11)` |
| `'Sunil'` | `c(1, 4, 11, 12)` |

To here:

| user-task |
| --- |
| `c('Bill-1', 'Bill-2', 'Bill-3')` |
| `c('Jae-2', 'Jae-5', 'Jae-6', 'Jae-7', 'Jae-8', 'Jae-9', 'Jae-10')` |
| `c('Marsha-1', 'Marsha-11')` |
| `c('Sunil-1', 'Sunil-4', 'Sunil-11', 'Sunil-12')` |

I tried things like using `paste0` to connect the user and task but I think that just ended up with this:

| user-task |
| --- |
| `Bill c(1, 2, 3)` |
| `Jae c(2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)` |
| `Marsha c(1, 11)` |
| `Sunil c(1, 4, 11, 12)` |

I have code for it, but I've been getting frustrated with trying to include code in this box. So many errors! It's like debugging StackOverflow after running my head into a wall debugging R. I fumbled a bit with `apply` options, but I'm still too new to really understand how to make use of it.

Comment: To insert code blocs you just use triple back-ticks in a line before and in a line after the code block. To insert inline code, single back ticks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have "c" function inside your dataframe. But see if this works:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% mutate(id = row_number()) %>% mutate(task = str_remove_all(task, '[c\\(||)]')) %>% separate_rows(task) %>% 
group_by(id) %>% transmute(usertask = str_c(user,'-',task, collapse = ',')) %>% ungroup() %>% select(-id) %>% distinct
# A tibble: 4 x 1
  usertask                                  
  <chr>                                     
1 Bill-1,Bill-2,Bill-3                      
2 Jae-2,Jae-5,Jae-6,Jae-7,Jae-8,Jae-9,Jae-10
3 Marsha-1,Marsha-11                        
4 Sunil-1,Sunil-4,Sunil-11,Sunil-12
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! The only issue I have is an error saying `1: Problem with 'mutate()' input 'task'. argument is not an atomic vector; coercing` but the output still looks like what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using `apply` and `paste`.

```
apply(d, 1, function(x) paste(x[1], unlist(x[2]), sep="-"))
# [[1]]
# [1] "Bill-1" "Bill-2" "Bill-3"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "Jae-2"  "Jae-3"  "Jae-4"  "Jae-5"  "Jae-6"  "Jae-7"  "Jae-8" 
# [8] "Jae-9"  "Jae-10"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "Marsha-1"  "Marsha-11"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "Sunil-1"  "Sunil-4"  "Sunil-11" "Sunil-12"
```

Or, using `do.call`.

```
apply(d, 1, function(x) do.call(paste0, c(sapply(x, unlist), "-")[c(1, 3, 2)]))
```

---

*Data*

```
d <- structure(list(user = c("Bill", "Jae", "Marsha", "Sunil"), task = structure(list(
    1:3, 2:10, c(1, 11), c(1, 4, 11, 12)), class = "AsIs")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Just for my own understanding, what does `c(1, 3, 2)` do in this syntax? Is that putting the "-" in between the other entries?

Comment: @Aaron Thx for your question. It's the `do.call` method, which might be useful for larger problems, the `c(c(1, 3, 2)` brings the `"-"` between the row values generated by `apply`. `do.call` calls the function and needs the other arguments in a list in the right order. Compare `2^3` and `do.call("^", list(2, 3))`, but that's beyond this question. Actually it's easier to use the standard way for your problem, see update.

Answer (score 0):

Could use unnest() too:

```
d %>%
unnest(cols=c(task)) %>%
mutate(user1 = paste0(user,"-",task)) %>%
group_by(user) %>%
summarise(user_task = paste(user1,collapse=", "))
```